# Could not connect BeSimpleSOAP client with a certificate

Tags: php, soap, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to send test message with my PHP SOAP client. I'm using BeSimpleSoap library because I had problems with standard PHP SOAP calss and NuSOAP class. 
I had downloaded successfully file which is protected by PKI. Part of the code is:

```
$OIB_URL="https://xxxx:8444/kpoib/kp_lista_aktiviranih_korisnika.txt";
$Cert_path="C:\\PKI\\servercert.pem";
$key_path="C:\\PKI\\cert_file.pem";
$FINA_APIS_cert="C:\\PKI\\FINA_APIS.pem";
$cert_password="xxx";

$handle = curl_init();
$options = array( 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO         => $FINA_APIS_cert,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD  => $cert_password ,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT        => $Cert_path,
    CURLOPT_SSLKEY         => $key_path,
    CURLOPT_SSLVERSION     => 3,
    CURLOPT_URL            => $OIB_URL
);

curl_setopt_array($handle, $options);


$OIB_File=(string)curl_exec($handle);
if (curl_errno($handle)) {
  echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($handle);
}
curl_close($handle);
```

Files are:

- soap_cert.pem is certificate signed by CA in PEM format
- cert_file.pem is encrypted private key and my IIS certificate in PEM format
- FINA_APIS.pem is certificate for server with which I'm communicating and CA root self signed certificate

I don't know how to pass these certificates and key to SoapClient in order to send test messages.
I have tried this:

```
    $par_data=array("KorisnickiPretinacPoruka" => 
        array("Zaglavlje"=>
            array("IdPosiljatelja"=>"000000001","IdPoruke"=>$UUID,"DatumVrijemeSlanja"=>$date_time,"RazinaSigurnosti"=>2),
                "Poruka" =>array("PinPrimatelja"=>$OIB,"OznakaDrzave"=>"HR","Predmet"=>$title,"Sadrzaj"=>$rows_lines)));

    $par_envelope=array( "GsbEnvelope" =>  
        array( "MessageHeader" => 
            array("SenderId" => "000000001",
                "ServiceId" => "000000002",
                "MessageId" => $UUID,
                "SenderTimeStamp" => $date_time),
                "Content" => array("MimeType" =>"application/xml","Data" =>array("encoding"=>"EMBEDDED","any"=>$par_data))));


    $client = new BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient("GSBService.wsdl", array( 
                    "trace"=>1,
                    "exceptions"=>1,
                    "local_cert" =>$key_path,
                    "passphrase"=>$cert_password,
                    "connection_timeout" => 30));


    print_r( $client->sendMessage($par_envelope));



    echo "<p>Request :".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) ."</p>";
    echo "<p>Response:".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse())."</p>";
    echo "<p>Debug:".soapDebug($client)."</p>";
```

The result was:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\BeSimpleSoap-master\src\BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient.php:146 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\BeSimpleSoap-master\src\BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient.php(203): BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient->__doHttpRequest(Object(BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapRequest)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\BeSimpleSoap-master\src\BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient.php(183): BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient->__doRequest2(Object(BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapRequest)) #2 [internal function]: BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://www.apis...', 'http://www.apis...', 1, 0) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\HZZO-OKP-SOAP.php(131): SoapClient->__call('sendMessage', Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\HZZO-OKP-SOAP.php(131): BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient->sendMessage(Array) #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\BeSimpleSoap-master\src\BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient.php on line 146
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well error is "Could not connect to host" and not some certificate error, so you have to check do you have connectivity to service.

And try this:

```
$client = new BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient("GSBService.wsdl", array( 
                "trace"=>1,
                "exceptions"=>1,
                "local_cert" =>$key_path,
                "passphrase"=>$cert_password,
                "connection_timeout" => 30));

// set direct location to service
$client->__setLocation(xxx);

print_r( $client->sendMessage($par_envelope));
```

HTH.

Comment: The port was blocked.

Comment: But I am getting this error now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724074/fatal-error-uncaught-soapfault-exception-envclient-internal-error